# Export db2 tables to xml file and read from xml and update the tables

Tags: java, xml

i am working on a project, where we need to migrate the data via xml. I am not sure how to do this, can some one please give me some advise or guide me to some tutorials or books. the tables have 1 to many and many to many relation ships too. we can have a seperate xml for each table, as single xml becomes too large. We are using Db2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To read/write date in database you need to use JDBC: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

To work with XML JAXB library is usually used: http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/

To read/write files use Java IO: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/index.html